# routing-filter does not work on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, locale

I am trying to convert `?locale=en` in routes to `/en/` I found [routing-filter](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter) gem
but if I try to run rails, I get this error:

```
samir@samir-VirtualBox:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ rails s
/home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- routing_filter/adapters/rails_4 (LoadError)
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/routing-filter-0.3.1/lib/routing_filter.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/routing-filter-0.3.1/lib/routing-filter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /home/samir/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the gem you are currently using is probably not compatible with Rails 4. You need to have version 0.4.0.pre, which can be installed through gem install routing-filter --pre or by editing your gemfile. I have found this issue, which relates to your problem: https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter/issues/48

Comment: How would I add gem install routing-filter --pre at Gemfile?

Comment: Ok! I found it here gem "routing-filter", "~> 0.4.0.pre"

Comment: Yep, can be found on rubygems. Was on my mobile phone, which made it harder to write down that line. :)

Comment: Thanks it worked, I can start rails now, but I don't know why en-us locale is enforced although I am using /en/ in route! any idea?

Comment: According to the issue I referred to, there are some problems with locales. Personally, I think you should ditch this gem altogether, since it is not maintained much. It seems some features which were available in earlier versions are no longer available in this pre-release.